# Different Internet Download Speed between macOS and Windows 10 for the same Ethernet Connection!

Tags: macos, mac, network, imac, internet

I have an Internet connection of 20 megabit per second. This is the download speed I get in Chrome/Firefox for Windows 10.

Now when I connect to the same Ethernet Connection via my iMac and download a particular/same file used to test the download speed in Windows, I get only 1 Mbps max, no matter which browser I use in my iMac the speed is same.

Why does this happen?

---

For macOS
cURL speed test:

```
$ curl -o /dev/null speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test500.zip 
% Total  % Received % Xferd Average Speed  Time    Time    Time    Current 
                            Dload   Upload Total   Spent   Left    Speed 
25 500M 25 128M     0 0     358k    0      0:23:48 0:06:07 0:17:41 320k

Max current speed: ~780k
```

Comment: Is this two *different computers* or is this via Bootcamp?

Comment: @Allan Two different Computers!

Comment: @klanomath Should I terminate the process after testing the download speed for the first few minutes?

Comment: @klanomath Result: Last login: Thu Sep 28 18:06:07 on ttys000
Sayans-iMac:~ sayan$ curl -o /dev/null http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test500.zip
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 25  500M   25  128M    0     0   358k      0  0:23:48  0:06:07  0:17:41  320k     The max was around 780K For macOS and and around 2500K for windows

Comment: I am waiting for your answer!

Comment: @Sayan There's no obvious answer. I'd assume a bad Ethernet cable or some kind of bandwidth throttling (or some bad driver if you was forced to install one)...

Comment: But in macOS I don't think there are drivers it's for windows

Comment: @klanomath But while downloading anything from the App Store I am getting a full download speed of 20 Mbps then why Safari is getting only 1 Mbps even downloading softwares from top sites like Android Developers(Android Studio)